# preg match all a tags with the same class from file_get_contents

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

i want to get all the a tags with the same class from html file,
i have tried:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://10tv.nana10.co.il/Category/?CategoryID=400008');
preg_match_all('/<a\s+class="FooterNavigationItemValue">(.*)<\/a>/', $html, $div_array); 
return var_dump($div_array);
```

but i get an empty array, help?

Comment: simple: don't use regexes on html. use DOM+XPATH. `//a[@class='FooterNavigationItemValue']` will be far more reliable.

Comment: what's the input and expected output?

Comment: @vks i want to get a array of all a tags

Comment: what does this mean....`with the same class`

Comment: @vks with the same class attribute

Comment: your example has only one a class

Comment: I have a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/34569269/5477982

Answer (score 3):

As Marc B commented, using DOM will be your best bet. But since you are looking for regex:

```
'#<a.*?class="FooterNavigationItemValue".*?>(.*?)</a>#s'
```

P.S. I looked into the site mentioned in the code and this piece of regex does its job perfectly.

Now the explanation:
the two `.*?` before and after `class="FooterNavigationItemValue"` is to make sure that the string still matches if there's something before and after `class="FooterNavigationItemValue"`.

And I used `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` to prevent regex greediness. More info can be found here: [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Comment: +1 for doing regex as requested and at least mentioning DOM. A little explanation would be nice since it didn't seem OP understood lazy matches.

Comment: ahh... I will add an explanation then :D

Comment: @sikhlana your regex not giving me all the a tags as array its giving me a strange array including divs

Comment: @user3519234 that is how PHP's preg_match_all works. You will get the text in between the `<a>` tags by dumping $div_array[1]. $div_array[0] contains the full string matched.